# Speed up creation of impoint objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have to create some draggable points on an axes. However, this seems to be a very slow process, on my machine taking a bit more than a second when done like so:

```
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);

tic;
for i = 1:100
    h(i) = impoint(gca, x(i), y(i));
end
toc;
```

Any ideas on speed up would be highly appreciated.

The idea is simply to provide the user with the possibility to correct positions in a figure that have been previously calculated by Matlab, here exemplified by the random numbers.

Comment: As 72% of the running time is consumed by the `impoint` function, there is hardly any margin to optimize it. Please provide some more context to see if there is a different approach from the scratch.

Comment: So how many of these 100 points are moved afterwards? I could imagine to plot the points conventionally and then use datatips and its callback function to just create a draggable point, if you really want to to drag it.

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea to me, how would you robustly choose the point you are changing though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the [**`ginput`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) cursor within a while loop to mark all points you want to edit. Afterwards just **click outside the axes** to leave the loop, move the points and accept with any key.

```
f = figure(1);
scatter(x,y);
ax = gca;
i = 1;
 while 1
        [u,v] = ginput(1);
        if ~inpolygon(u,v,ax.XLim,ax.YLim); break; end;
        [~, ind] = min(hypot(x-u,y-v));
        h(i).handle = impoint(gca, x(ind), y(ind));
        h(i).index  = ind;
        i = i + 1;
 end
```

[image]

---

Depending on how you're updating your plot you can gain a general speedup by using functions like  [**`clf`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) (clear figure) and [**`cla`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html) (clear axes) instead of always opening a new figure window as explained in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29373562/2605073) are may useful.

---

Alternatively the following is a very rough idea of what I meant in the comments. It throws various errors and I don't have the time to debug it right now. But maybe it helps as a starting point.

1) Conventional plotting of data and activating of datacursormode

```
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
xlim([0 1]); ylim([0 1])

f = figure(1)
scatter(x,y)

datacursormode on
dcm = datacursormode(f);
set(dcm,'DisplayStyle','datatip','Enable','on','UpdateFcn',@customUpdateFunction)
```

2) Custom update function evaluating the chosen datatip and creating an `impoint`

```
function txt = customUpdateFunction(empt,event_obj)

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
ax = get(event_obj.Target,'parent');
sc = get(ax,'children');

x = sc.XData;
y = sc.YData;
mask = x == pos(1) & y == pos(2);
x(mask) = NaN;
y(mask) = NaN;
set(sc, 'XData', x, 'YData', y);
set(datacursormode(gcf),'Enable','off')

impoint(ax, pos(1),pos(2));
delete(findall(ax,'Type','hggroup','HandleVisibility','off'));

txt = {};
```

It works for the, if you'd just want to move one point. Reactivating the datacursormode and setting a second point fails:

[image]

Maybe you can find the error.